# Multiple barplots using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe named frame. [Click here to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgq2p.jpg). It has 20 rows. I wish to obtain barplots in a 4x5 matrix using ggplot. In every barplot D05, D12, D18 and D28 are on the x-axis and the corresponding values on the y-axis. I am aware that this can be done using facet_wrap. I tried the following but did not get the intended results:

`ggplot(data = frame[,-1], aes(x = frame$Date)) +
 geom_bar() +
 facet_wrap( ~ frame$Date, ncol = 5)`

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reshape the data first.

## Data

Please try to put this chunk in your question next time, also specify the error message.

```
a <- data.frame( Date = c("2017-04",
                          "2017-05",
                          "2017-06",
                          "2017-07",
                          "2017-08",
                          "2017-09",
                          "2017-10",
                          "2017-11",
                          "2017-12",
                          "2018-01",
                          "2018-02"),
                 DO5 = c(0,0,0,15,18,21,23,15,18,15,11),
                 D12 = c(0,0,0,605,737,620,642,599,607,663,548),
                 D18 = c(36,33,38,7,13,15,13,24,40,37,25),
                 D28 = c(502,626,627,28,35,40,19,17,6,1,1)
)
```

## Reshape it

Yo can do this with many packages in this case i use the eassiest one (code wise).

```
install.packages("reshape2")
library(reshape2)                 

b <- melt(a)

head(b)
names(b)
```

## Now the plot

You dont need to use the **"$"** operator in ggplot2. (And most of the time when you specify the argument **data** in the function you are ussing)

```
  library(ggplot2)

  ggplot(data = b, aes(x = variable, y = value)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
      facet_wrap( ~ Date, ncol = 5)
```

[image: The result is this]

Comment: Thank you so much. I will make sure to specify the code and error message next time.

Comment: @ Akshit Bhalla well I think you also should say that the problem is solved so it gets green.